# ios "smart" location tracker and battery drain

Tags: ios, gps, location, battery

I'm creating an activity tracker similar to the "Moves" app that seeks to track steps, distance, calories and active time.

For Iphone5s+ devices, I am using the built in M7 chip to determine Steps, and then making estimates at the rest from that.  For M7 devices I never use GPS.  There is basically no battery drain and the interpolated numbers are reasonable enough for the need.  This gets walking/running data reasonably enough.

However to support Iphone5 and Iphone4 at least, I need to use GPS to get location and then interpolate steps and calories from the distance.  I'm running into significant battery drain issues (somewhat expected), and am seeking advice on how to minimize this.  I'm also using the accelerometer in addition to speed to help make an educated guess on activity type (walking,running,biking,transport)

Some things I've tried for GPS optimization:

1. **Deferred Updates**:  The Iphone5 and a minimum version of IOS supports this.  The code to do this is straight forward, however whether the device actually uses it is questionable.  I've only seen it work on 1 out of 4 devices, where it does regularly.  3 other devices have never deferred updates from the same code.  Another user suggested other apps prevent the device from sleeping, including when I had "Moves" also installed. This thus hasn't helped much beyond theory.
2. **Reduce Accuracy**: reduce the accuracy of continuous location polling.  I started at High, but reduced to 10m, then hundreds of meters, etc.  This doesn't seem to help and polling still seems to occur at a regular interval anyway.
3. **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**:  In order to reduce endless gps polling when the user may not be moving for hours at a time (especially at night), I switched from continuous polling to significant changes only after the device stopped moving for an arbitrary 2 minutes.  I then re enable continuous tracking after any significant location update.  This works pretty much as expected-- if it stops tracking then battery drain slows, and when it resumes continuously, battery drain resumes.  Further, if a user starts walking, there is no guarantee of a significant motion event for some time. This is very poor for accuracy.  Sometimes it doesn't seem to resume at all.

I've been relatively impressed that the "Moves" app, among others is able to track location so well with respectable battery drain.  It can go most of a day until needing a charge.  With my code, users have reported full battery drain in a couple of hours.

What kind of optimizations could be used to improve this but still maintain a reasonable accuracy in tracking movement?

**PROGRESS UPDATE:**
**startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**.  I set this up with a timer that switches to significant monitoring after 2 minutes of inactivity (not moving).  Normal location tracking is then resumed again on any significant change, or when the app becomes active from reopening. This seems to work well.  My phone still goes from 100% to 10% in 8 hours overnight of sitting around.  It is an old iphone with some battery troubles, but normally it might just lose 30-40% uncharged overnight with no apps running. I need to test more, but startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges still seems to use some battery.

Further, startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges has some expected accuracy issues in terms of when it restarts the app.  In rural setting, it can go several kilometers before restarting.  This could be okay for a long drive, but **if I want to catch a 30 minute walk, it may miss that entirely.** In urban setting it seems to kick in within 2-3 blocks of movement, which is reasonable.

Even if I used continuous location tracking that stopped+started on a timer to check for movement, I'd still likely have worst case of a minute of lag between restarts before resuming continuous logging.

**PROGRESS UPDATE 2**:

Significant change updates described above have a fatal flaw for me: they don't always start fast enough.  Sometimes it takes 1-2 miles it seems!

As an a better approach, I've tried keeping continuous location updates on, but toggling the "desiredAccuracy" property from high to low accuracy when the device is not moving.  This should essentially turn the GPS receiver off during inactivity.  I've been experimenting between 100meter and 1km accuracy for inactivity with promising results.  It does seem to use slightly more batter than only using significant change monitoring, but it seems more responsive as well.

Comment: Can you please comment how many hours Moves works until battery empty. And how many hours your current App?

Comment: I will need to test this comparison.  Doing active development on a single device means everyday involves full day testing.  Perhaps on the weekend I can do these devoted tests.

Comment: Alright, I tested on a hihking tour. The battery lasted longer than my fitness (or the length of the planned hiking tour) , so after 8 hours still there was battery remaining.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing of your above proposed solutions works.
You need GPS, and that is enabled if you speficiy full precision (`CLLocationAcuracyBest`).

if I remeber correctly there is a difference betwween CLLocationAcuracyBest and CLLocationAcuracyBestForNavigation that way that the latter uses additonaly the acceleration sensor, which in sum uses more battery.

There is no half battery GPS mode!
A GPS chip is enabled or not.

For distance counting you need GPS, cell Tower and Wlan locations will not work.
And only the cell tower an Wlan locationg can save battery.

On Iphone4 such an full precision GPS App (e.g my) lasts about 8 hours untill the battery is low.

8 hours are enough, if the user has a benefit of the app.

Comment: Do you know which precision level would use celltower + wifi exclusively?  Or is there no guarantee about that?

Comment: From apple docs: "setting the desired accuracy for location events to one kilometer gives the location manager the flexibility to turn off GPS hardware and rely solely on the WiFi or cell radios. Turning off GPS hardware can lead to significant power savings."

Comment: There is no garuantee, but yes, 1km will use cell tower in cities, but may use GPS in rural areas, because there the cell tower is often 3km away.